# Upgrading WD Mycloud EX2 Ultra NAS Drives

Tags: hard-drive, raid, nas, upgrade

I have a Mycloud Ex2 Ultra with 2x2TB NAS drives configured in RAID 1, with a total of 1TB of storage used.  Recently tried to upgrade the drives to 6TB because I intend to use the NAS for much more storage, and for backups from multiple users.  I had mixed results.

I hibernated the unit, replaced one 2TB drive with the new 6TB, and restarted.  The NAS showed "Volume Degraded" as expected, and I manually rebuilt the RAID volume.  So far so good.

Repeated the process with the other drive, successfully rebuilt the RAID volume.  At this point, the dashboard showed correctly that the storage capacity was 6TB, but on the home page there is only 1TB free.

I went back to the "change RAID mode" and tried to expand the volume... I've done so several times, but each time it completes there is a total capacity of 2TB.  The firmware and apps are up to date, what am I missing?

I read some discussion from other users who said that hibernating the unit between disk changes was a mistake, and there should have been an option to increase the size of the disk being replaced.  I never saw that.

So I currently have access to all of my NAS data, as before.  I just don't have the increased capacity.  I *DO* have the option of adding another volume in the unused space (under the storage tab), but I think I'm making things more complicated. I also have a full backup of the data on an external drive, so in the worst case I could change the RAID mode to 0, then change it back to 1, effectively wiping all of the data and in theory the new volume should be the full capacity?  Then I could restore the backup to the NAS... This seems more complicated than it should be.

Would appreciate any advice on where to go from here.

Comment: Is the NAS supposed to auto extend the partition and filesystem when it detects a change of capacity of the RAID anyway? It doesn't seem that you have taken any step for that?

Comment: I have very little documentation from WD - and can't find much either!  As far as I can tell, the expansion step is available AFTER you have replaced the drives one at a time, with a RAID rebuild in between.  There is a STORAGE tab on the MyCloud web app, and it correctly shows a new capacity of 6TB, but on the home screen it shows only 1TB free.

Comment: There is a link to expand the volume, but it has run for several hours 4 different times, run to completion because I watched it finish, and the volume capacity is still 2TB.  There is a link on the STORAGE tab (that wasn't there previously) that asks if you want to add a new volume with the unused space.  I'm thinking that I may reset the NAS, wipe the data and just start again - I was able to use the WD USB storage app to connect an external drive, and copy all of the folder shares to the external drive.

Comment: It just shouldn't be this hard?  The lack of documentation from WD is really troubling me.  I have a call into WD tech support, who promised to remotely connect to my laptop and look at the situation...